# Deleting first item in python dict using indexes

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with dictionaries and I would like to delete the first item of the dictionary.
Is there any way to do  that using indexes?

Comment: Dict objects *don't have indices*. They do maintain insertion order, but this is an indication that you are using the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python dictionaries preserve insertion order. So if you want to delete the first inserted `(key, value)` pair from it you can do it this way, for example:

```py
>>> d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4}
>>> del d[list(d.keys())[0]]
>>> print(d)
{'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
```

Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: `list(d.keys())` -> `list(d)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah, right. But I'll leave my answer as it is. I believe it is more understandable for newcomers to Python this way.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Yevgeniy-Kosmak above but you can avoid allocating the list of keys and use a lazy iterator. This will be friendlier to memory with large dicts:

```
d = {
    'x': 100,
    'y': 200,
    'z': 300
}

del d[next(iter(d))]

d
# {'y': 200, 'z': 300}
```

Of course, this should include a caveat that if you are depending on the order of things, a dictionary may not be the best choice of data structure.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to add that my solution's time complexity is `O(n)` and it's suitable only for short `dict`s.

Comment: Or, more generally, `next(islice(d, n, n + 1))`

Comment: The other answer was deleted but it did point out that the `popitem` of `OrderedDict` can do this without accessing the keys view manually. Not sure why the `popitem` of a `dict` doesn't support this